# qprocess with gstreamer pipeline

Tags: c++, qt, process, gstreamer

I want to save the output of videotestsrc to a 20 seconds-long avi file in size of 1024x720 and I want gplay to be able to play it. In command line,  pipeline below does what I want.

```
gst-launch -ve videotestsrc ! 'video/x-raw-yuv,width=1024,height=720,framerate=15/1,format(fourcc)I420' ! queue ! mfw_vpuencoder codec-type=2 ! queue ! avimux ! filesink location=test.avi
```

After 20 seconds, I kill this pipeline with kill -2.

But when I try to run this pipeline with qprocess and kill it with kill -2 from code, gplay cannot play the video file. Also, when I change the size information to 640x480 and run it as a qprocess, gplay can play it. I want to know what my mistake is. Why doesn't this pipeline work with qprocess?

Qt code:

```
QStringList args;
args << "-ve";
args << "videotestsrc";
args << "!";
args << "video/x-raw-yuv,width=1024,height=720,framerate15/1,format(fourcc)I420";
args << "!";
args << "queue";
args << "mfw_vpuencoder codec-type=2";
args << "!";
args << "queue";
args << "!";
args << "avimux";
args << "!";
args << "filesink location=test.avi";

process->start("gst-launch", args);
usleep( 20000000 ); //20secs
kill( process->pid(), 2 );
```

PS: When I change size information at the code above to 640x480, gplay plays the video with no problem.

Comment: Why are you killing it?

Comment: I am killing it to end saving video to file. After starting to save video to file, it continues to save until it is killed.

Comment: Sounds horrible; is there is no way to make it terminate by itself when it's done the conversion?

Comment: No. videotestsrc produces video forever. In order to stop videotestrc to produce video is to kill it.